# Chat with WSS on AWS Lightsail

Tags: laravel, websocket, wss, ratchet, amazon-lightsail

I built chat functions with Ratchet/Laravel.
It works well on local I figured out the SSL too.

[Websocket with laravel](https://medium.com/@errohitdhiman/real-time-one-to-one-and-group-chat-with-php-laravel-ratchet-websocket-library-javascript-and-c64ba20621ed)

But after deploying on AWS/Lightsail, WSS is not working.
I think there is some configuration required to make WebSocket work on AWS or Lightsail.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experiencing the same issue. I believe it is due to the fact that the lightsail load balancer only supports HTTP(S), while WSS is a different protocol. I believe that if you setup a load balancer from regular AWS (without Lightsail), it will work.